# Proof for a simple probability inequality

Tags: probability

Let A and B be events in $\Omega$.

Then, 
$$P(A,B)^2 \le P(A)P(B). $$
Is this true? What to use to construct a proof?

Comment: For mutually exclusive events $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$, if probabilities are $\leq 1$ then what can you say about the square of $P(A,B)$?

Comment: Mind refreshing us about the meaning of $P(A,B)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true, assuming I understand your notations, i.e. that $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space (the first thing necessary in order to "construct a proof" is to define carefully and non-ambiguously the quantities and concepts you are dealing with). You have (again, interpreting the notation $P(A,B)$ as $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$) that
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \leq \min(\mathbb{P} A,\mathbb{P} B)$$
as $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$.

Then,
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)^2 \leq \min(\mathbb{P} A,\mathbb{P} B)^2 \leq \mathbb{P} A \cdot \mathbb{P} B.$$